# Comparing ASM MethodNode parameters

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to create an method that compares the parameters of 2 methods and give me an percentage of matching parameters, like:

```
Method1(int i, boolean b, char c)    
Method2(boolean b, int i)   
Method3(char c)    
Method4(double d)


Method1 and Method2 = 66% -> 2 matching parameters    
Method1 and Method3 = 33% -> 1 matching parameter
Method1 and Method4 = 0%  -> 0 matching parameters
```

Can someone give me a clue how to do this?

Comment: looks rather like a question for a compiler than for a Java program. Fromw within a program you can not inspect methods, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated with Holger's tips

```
private static float compare(MethodNode mn1, MethodNode mn2) {
    Type[] typeArgs1 = Type.getArgumentTypes(mn1.desc);
    Type[] typeArgs2 = Type.getArgumentTypes(mn2.desc);
    int max = Math.max(typeArgs1.length, typeArgs2.length);
    if (max == 0)
        return 1f;
    int matches = 0;
    List<Type> types = Arrays.asList(typeArgs1);
    for (Type arg : typeArgs2)
        if (types.contains(arg))
            matches++;
    return ((float) matches / max);
}
```

Original Code:

```
private static float compare(MethodNode mn1, MethodNode mn2) {
    Type t1 = Type.getMethodType(mn1.desc);
    Type t2 = Type.getMethodType(mn2.desc);
    Type[] targs1 = t1.getArgumentTypes();
    Type[] targs2 = t2.getArgumentTypes();
    int max = Math.max(targs1.length, targs2.length);
    int matches = 0;
    if (max == 0) 
        return 1f;
    List<String> types1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Type t : targs1) 
        types1.add(t.getDescriptor());
    for (Type t : targs2) 
        if (types1.contains(t.getDescriptor())) 
            matches++;  
    return (1F * matches / max);
}
```

Output for your example methods:

```
0,1  0.0
0,2  0.0
0,3  0.0
0,4  0.0
1,2  0.6666667
1,3  0.33333334
1,4  0.0
2,3  0.0
2,4  0.0
3,4  0.0
```

Comment: It would make more sense to declare `types1` as `Set` (using, e.g. a `HashSet`). Further, multiplying with `1F` obfuscates the actual intent of doing a simple conversion from `int`  to `float`. Just use a type cast, `(float)matches` instead. Note that you can simplify your code, you can simply use [`Type.getArgumentTypes(desc)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getArgumentTypes-java.lang.String-) without the detour via `Type.getMethodType`. You can also utilize the fact that `Type` already implements `equals` and `hashCode`, so you don’t need `getDescriptor()`

Comment: I updated the snippet with your suggestions except for using a HashSet. Instead I used `Arrays.asList` snce it inlined an extra two lines. The extra step of `new HashSet<Type>(Arrays.asList(typeArgs1));` to create a `Set<Type>` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Seems fair. The number of parameter types is usually very small and limited to `255` anyway, so the lightweight `Arrays.toList` wrapper will perform better than copying to a `HashSet` in most cases. But note that you have a code duplication; you are calling `Type.getArgumentTypes(mn2.desc)` twice instead of using the `typeArgs2` variable.

Comment: Opps I missed that.